# Firestore keep loading old changes

Tags: react-native, google-cloud-firestore, react-native-firebase

I'm trying to create a firestore listener, which handles changes on my collection. After some research, I implement the feature as below.

```js
useEffect(() => {
  const firebaseApp = getFirebaseApp();
  const db = firestore(firebaseApp);
  const handleSnapshotChanges = ( snapshot: FirebaseFirestoreTypes.QuerySnapshot<FirebaseFirestoreTypes.DocumentData> ) => {
    const changes = snapshot.docChanges();

    changes.forEach((change) => {
      if (change.type === "added") {
        console.log(change.doc);
        console.log(change.type);
      }
      if (change.type === "modified") {
        console.log("Doc modified");
      }
      if (change.type === "removed") {
        console.log("Remove doc");
      }
    });
  };

  const query = db.collection("history");
  const unsubscribe = query.onSnapshot(handleSnapshotChanges, (err) =>
    console.log(err)
  );

  return () => {
    unsubscribe();
  };
}, []);
```

If I doing so, every time I enter the screen where I put the above useEffect, firestore keeps loading all documents in the collection and marks them as **added**. How can I implement this function properly.

Comment: The behavior you're describing is as I expect the API to work: every time you add a new `onSnapshot` listener, it initially gets a snapshot of all documents matching the query. This allows the app to build the initial UI for the database contents. What isn't proper about this for your use-case?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen The behavior I expected is the listener will only listen new changes, instead of all documents and mark them as newly added. I just find out that I should avoid putting this useEffect inside any screen, but in the App.js, so it will trigger only once, instead of every time I enter the screen where I put it. For now, the app work correctly. But there is an issue remain: every time I refresh the app (just like ctrl S on IDE), the useEffect is fired and the above issue appear again.